# Exercise 4.6 (iii) in the HoTT Book

Tags: homotopy-type-theory

Being unable to solve Exercise 4.6 (iii) in the [HoTT Book](http://homotopytypetheory.org/book/), I'd be most grateful for any help.

Recall the statement of Exercise 4.6:

For $A,B:\mathcal U$, define
$$
\mathsf{idtoqinv}_{A,B}:(A=B)\to\sum_{f:A\to B}\mathsf{qinv}(f)
$$
by path induction in the obvious way. Let $\mathsf{qinv}$-$\mathsf{univalence}$ denote the modified form of the univalence axiom which asserts that for all $A,B:\mathcal U$ the function $\mathsf{idtoqinv}_{A,B}$ has a quasi-inverse.

(i) Show that $\mathsf{qinv}$-$\mathsf{univalence}$ can be used instead of univalence in the proof of function extensionality in $\S$4.9.

(ii) Show that $\mathsf{qinv}$-$\mathsf{univalence}$ can be used instead of univalence in the proof of Theorem 4.1.3.

(iii) Show that $\mathsf{qinv}$-$\mathsf{univalence}$ is inconsistent (i.e. allows construction of an inhabitant of **0**). Thus, the use of a "good" version of $\mathsf{isequiv}$ is essential in the statement of univalence.

Comment: All three problems, or just one?

Comment: @AndrejBauer - Just one, just part (iii).

Comment: Hmm, I seem to remember Mike Shulman outlining an argument on a mailing list or in a GitHub issue, if you want to practice your Google powers...

Comment: @AndrejBauer - Thanks! I found 3 links: https://github.com/HoTT/book/issues/563 - https://groups.google.com/d/msg/homotopytypetheory/EXWVbQNRAdE/ct89FgY1kVUJ - https://groups.google.com/d/msg/homotopytypetheory/EXWVbQNRAdE/8g6Xx7aLQeoJ, but I'm unable to exploit them...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As observed by Luis, it suffices to show that, for any map $f:A\to B$, the type $\mathsf{qinv}(f)$ is a mere proposition.

For any types $A$ and $B$ we put 
$$
(A\simeq B):\equiv\sum_{f:A\to B}\mathsf{ishae}(f),\quad(A\backsimeq B):\equiv\sum_{f:A\to B}\mathsf{qinv}(f).
$$ 
(Recall that $\mathsf{ishae}(f)$ stands for "$f$ is a half-adjoint equivalence".) By Theorem 4.2.3 and the comment preceding it, there are dependent functions 
$$
i:\prod_{A,B:\mathcal U}\prod_{f:A\to B}\mathsf{ishae}(f)\to\mathsf{qinv}(f),\quad p:\prod_{A,B:\mathcal U}\prod_{f:A\to B}\mathsf{qinv}(f)\to\mathsf{ishae}(f).
$$ 
For all $A,B:\mathcal U$ let $e(A,B):(A=B)\to(A\backsimeq B)$ be the natural map (which we assume to admit a quasi-inverse).

Claim: if $f:A\to B$ and $x:\mathsf{qinv}(f)$, then $i(A,B,f,p(A,B,f,x))=x$.

Since $(f,x):A\backsimeq B$, we can assume by $\mathsf{qinv}$-univalence and path induction that 
$$
B\equiv A,\quad f\equiv\mathsf{id}_A,\quad x\equiv e(A,A,\mathsf{refl}_A),
$$ 
and the claim follows easily from the definition of $i,p$ and $e$.

For $f:A\to B$ and $x,y:\mathsf{qinv}(f)$ we have $p(A,B,f,x)=p(A,B,f,y)$ because $\mathsf{ishae}(f)$ is a mere proposition, and the claim implies $x=y$, as required.

Comment: @LuisNScoccola - Thanks! Let's try to agree first on the correctness of your answer. Here is how I "understand" it. Let $u,v:\mathsf{qinv}(f)$. You show $$\pi_1(\mathsf{lemma'}_{A,B}(f,u))(u)=\pi_1(\mathsf{lemma'}_{A,B}(f,v))(v).$$ In other words, $u$ and $v$ have the same image under two *a priori* distinct equivalences. How do you conclude that $u=v$? (Do you agree that $\pi_1(\mathsf{lemma'}_{A,B}(f,u))$ and $\pi_1(\mathsf{lemma'}_{A,B}(f,v))$ are *a priori* distinct?)

Comment: The above comments refer to a previous version of the answer.

Comment: [Reading notes](http://iecl.univ-lorraine.fr/~Pierre-Yves.Gaillard/HoTT/ReadingNotes/HoTT_Reading_Notes_a.pdf) about the HoTT Book.