# Proof that the type of homotopy equivalence is not a proposition

Tags: type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

I've seen in The HoTT Book that assuming univalence for homotopy equivalences is inconsistent (this is Exercise 4.6). On some page, I've read that this is because without this "qinv-univalence", the type of homotopy equivalences is not a proposition, but assuming it, one can prove otherwise.

Recall that the type of homotopy equivalences is (under function extensionality):

$$
A \cong B :\equiv \sum\limits_{f: A \rightarrow B}\sum\limits_{g: B \rightarrow A}(\operatorname{id} A = g\circ f)\,\times\,(\operatorname{id} B = f\circ g)
$$

Now, I haven't been able to find a proof of the claim that this type isn't a proposition (and I haven't been able to prove it myself). I've looked into the [HoTT repository](https://github.com/HoTT/HoTT) (but I quickly get lost in Coq files; it's possible the proof is in there), I've searched nLab, and did a blind web search.

Can someone please either show me the proof or point me to one?

**Note:** I imagine a counterexample would be the most easiest.

Comment: The proof of exercise 4.6 (iii) is given here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1154148/exercise-4-6-iii-in-the-hott-book?rq=1

Comment: The proof of Exercise 4.6 in the HoTT Coq repository starts [here](https://github.com/HoTT/HoTT/blob/master/contrib/HoTTBookExercises.v#L998).